# How to collect a continuous set of webpages using python?

Tags: python, regex, url, beautifulsoup, matching

https://example.net/users/x

Here, x is a number that ranges from 1 to 200000. I want to run a loop to get all the URLs and extract contents from every URL using beautiful soup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re
content = urlopen(re.compile(r"https://example.net/users/[0-9]//"))
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
```

Is this the right approach? I have to perform two things.

1. Get a continuous set of URLs
2. Extract & store retrieved contents from every page/URL.

**UPDATE:**

I've to get only one particular value from each of the webpages.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
divTag = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"classname"})
for tag in divTag:
 ulTags = tag.find_all("ul", {"class":"classname"})
 for tag in ulTags:
  aTags = tag.find_all("a",{"class":"classname"})
  for tag in aTags:
   name = tag.find('img')['alt']
   print(name)
```

Comment: Why are you using Beautiful soup? You just need the contents, right?

Comment: @thefourtheye By contents I meant 'name' according to the code I've added now. Please do look into it.

Comment: I am sorry, I am still not sure what you are trying to do. The question is not very clear IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
import urllib2
import shutil

urls = []
for i in range(10):
    urls.append(str('https://www.example.org/users/' + i))


def getUrl(urls):
    for url in urls:
        # Only a file_name based on url string
        file_name = url.replace('https://', '').replace('.', '_').replace('/', '_')
        response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        with open(file_name, 'wb') as out_file:
            shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)

getUrl(urls)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the contents of a web page, you could probably use `lxml`, from which you could parse the content. Something like:

```
from lxml import etree
r = requests.get('https://example.net/users/x')
dom = etree.fromstring(r.text)
# parse seomthing
title = dom.xpath('//h1[@class="title"]')[0].text
```

Additionally, if you are scraping 10s or 100s of thousands of pages, you might want to look into something like [grequests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/grequests)  where you can do multiple asynchronous HTTP requests.

Comment: @shahnazshariff the last line is just an example of parsing a hypothetical 'title' on the page that you are requesting. I am using the XPATH to parse the element. In your case, it would be something like: `dom.xpath('//a[@class="classname"]/img')[0].attrib['alt']`